# re.MULTILINE flag is interfering with the end of line $ operator

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

Sorry if this is a duplicate/basic question, I couldn't find any similar questions.

I have the following multiline string

```
my_txt = """
foo.exe\n
bar.exec\n
abab.exe\n
"""
```

(The newlines aren't actually written in my code, I put them there for clarity).
I want to match every file that ends with a .exe, (not .exec).
My regex was initially:

```
my_reg = re.compile(".+[.](?=exe$)")
my_matches = my_reg.finditer(my_txt)
```

I hoped that it would first find every character, go back until it found the `.`, and then check if the characters `exe` and a newline followed.
Only one match was found, and that was:
`abab.exe`.
I tried to mess around a bit, and changed the first line:
`my_reg = re.compile(".+[.](?=exe$)",flags=re.MULTILINE)`.
This time, it successfully ran, returning

```
foo.
abab.
```

I thought re.MULTILINE wasn't supposed to interfere with the $ operator, or am I wrong about the $ operator/misusing something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want to include ".exe" at the end or no?

Comment: It really doesn't matter to me, I'm mainly concerned about finding the filename foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need the multiline flag, otherwise `$` will only match the absolute end of your input. You just need to match `exe` instead of using a lookahead:

```
my_reg = re.compile(".+[.]exe$", re.MULTILINE)
```

Output:

```
['foo.exe', 'abab.exe']
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RrmYsJ/2)

If you are trying to match the filename without the extension, you can put the period inside the lookahead:

```
my_reg = re.compile(r".+(?=\.exe$)", re.MULTILINE)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'abab']
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8zknZ/2)